# AutoIt - DllCall - my dll call does not return the value

Tags: autoit

I created my own dll using - C#, vb.net and FreeBasic -
Function is to add 2 nos.
The return value is either blank (when FreeBasic is used) or 0 (for c# and vb.net).

Can someone help me in this matter?

AutoIt code is simple as below:

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
;Local $hDLL = DllOpen(@ScriptDir & "\clsAddMul.dll") ; vb.net & c#
Local $hDLL = DllOpen(@ScriptDir & "\Math1.dll") ;FreeBasic

Local $aResult = 555

$aResult = DllCall($hDLL, "Int", "_add", "Int", 7, "Int", 8)
;$aResult = DllCall($hDLL, "int", "_add", "int", 7, "int", 8)

DllClose($hDLL)

MsgBox (0, "Result", "Total = " & $aResult)
```

Function code is as follows:

1 - FreeBasic code:

```
Extern "Windows-MS"

Function _add(no1 As Integer, no2 As Integer) As Integer Export
    Dim result As Integer
    result = no1 + no2
'   result = 10

'   Return no1+no2  
    Return result   

End Function
End Extern
```

Similarly without Extern and Export etc. for the vb.net and c# also.
Not included it here bcos its very simple example.

Comment: The return result is in `$aResult[0]`, not `$aResult`. Printing the array variable without an index will print nothing. Tested the compiled `Math1.dll` and `Msgbox` displays `Total = 15`.

Comment: Thanks - it did work.

Comment: Taking this further and as wellknown, to pass large amount of data, can we have function of Freebasic to return say Array or String or Type or an Object etc. datatype. How do I receive he same in the AutoIt code i.e. what will be DllCall return type definition for each of the types mentioned above? Can you please help about this?

Comment: String should be similar to your example. `DllCall` in help file lists data types that can be returned. Type or object is uncertain. For arrays, view the example by Larsj at the AutoIt forum, which displays a way to [Accessing AutoIt Arrays](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/193146-accessing-autoit-arrays/). You may need to do more searching to learn more.